# Inserting space after 5 characters when counting reverse

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which has many entries as below :

```
US6DWMD01#DW01DDATAPURGE(060009/28)
US6DWMD01#DW01DDATAPURGE(060009/29)
US6DWMD01#DW01DDATAPURGE(060009/30)
US6DWMD01#DW01DDATAPURGE(060011/01)
US6DWMD01#DW11WPURESUN(060011/01)
US6TPA01#PPAORD__LDBASE(000009/26)
US6TPA01#PPAORD__LGBOX(000009/26)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__DEDMGT(060009/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__FLNET(060009/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__LORTBLS(060009/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__PPATTBLS(060009/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__P8020RP(060011/01)
```

I want use cut/sed/awk commands to insert space after 5 characters when counting reverse as below :

```
US6TPA01#PPATDD__DEDMGT(0600 09/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__FLNET(0600 09/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__LORTBLS(0600 09/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__PPATTBLS(0600 09/25)
US6TPA01#PPATDD__P8020RP(0600 11/01)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 6 character, in fact: 2 digits, 1 slash, 2 digits, 1 parenthesis:

```
sed 's/.\{6\}$/ &/' < input > output
```

The `$` matches the end of line.

Answer (score 3):

In regular expressions, `$` matches the end of the line. You can therefore use it to match the last 6 (your question mentions 5 but you show 6, unless there is a trailing space you aren't showing us) characters and add a space before them. For example:

- Sed:

  ```
  sed 's/......$/ &/' file
  ```

  or

  ```
  sed 's/.\{6\}$/ &/' file
  ```
- GNU or FreeBSD sed:

  ```
  sed -E 's/.{6}$/ &/' file
  ```
- Perl

  ```
  perl -pe 's/.{6}$/ $&/' file
  ```
- awk

  ```
  awk '{sub(/.{6}$/," &");print}' file
  ```

Comment: `perl -pe 'substr $_, -7, 0, " "'`

Comment: The command perl -pe 'substr $_, -7, 0, " "' worked well , but not others.

Comment: @sriram2207 how did they fail? I tested all of them and they work as expected on your example file.